# could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (100)

Tags: python, data-mining

i want to solve this problem.... I am completely beginner

"could not broadcast input array from shape (100,2) into shape (100) "

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X_iris = iris.data
    y_iris = iris.target
    
    k_means= cluster.KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
    k_means.fit(X_iris)
    print(k_means.labels_[::10])
    print(y_iris[::10]
    df = make_blobs()
    from sklearn import metrics
    
    n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    for k in n_clusters:
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 42).fit(df)
        cluster_labels = kmeans.predict(df)
        S = metrics.silhouette_score(df, cluster_labels)
        print("n_clusters = {:d}, silhouette score {:1f}".format(k, S))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a parentheses line 10 of that code snippet.

```
    from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
    
    iris = datasets.load_iris()
    X_iris = iris.data
    y_iris = iris.target
    
    k_means= cluster.KMeans(n_clusters = 3)
    k_means.fit(X_iris)
    print(k_means.labels_[::10])
    print(y_iris[::10]) #MISSING A PARENTHESES
    df = make_blobs()
    from sklearn import metrics
    
    n_clusters = [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
    for k in n_clusters:
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, random_state = 42).fit(df)
        cluster_labels = kmeans.predict(df)
        S = metrics.silhouette_score(df, cluster_labels)
        print("n_clusters = {:d}, silhouette score {:1f}".format(k, S))
```